# Making an image appear as though it's getting closer - CSS Perspective?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate an image on the home screen (a plane flying) and want to make it appear as though the plane begins in the distance and gets closer as time goes on.

I've got two images layered on one another to create a 3D effect and have been able to animate the "sky" background successfully to make it appear as though the plane is moving. I can easily animate the plane using animate.css to fly in from above or below, but what I would rather achieve is a sort of perspective. I've played around with perspective property but haven't gotten it to work in any reasonable fashion yet.

When I try to scale the img of the plane, I begin with a negative number (which all that does is flip the img upside down). Starting with 1 and scaling to higher doesn't really make it seem as though the plane is starting small in the distance and getting larger as it approaches the viewer.

Any thoughts on this?

```css
.jumbotron {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url('../img/fluffy-cloud-cloudscape-sky-584414.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  animation: animatedBackground 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 1510px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="assets/img/stealth.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

There is no CSS for the plane img because nothing has come close to working to achieve this effect yet.

Also would love for this border to go away when the background picture changes on its infinite animation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *animate* the `width` & `height` of the plane `img`:

```css
body {width:100%;margin:0}

.jumbotron {
  /*z-index: 1; the element needs to be positioned anything else other than static to be taken into account */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2)), url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk18j.png') repeat-y;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    animation: animateBackground 3s linear infinite; 
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container > img {
  display: block;
  animation: animatePlate 3s linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes animatePlate {
  from {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 1510px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://cdn.officialpsds.com/imageview/78/5z/785z6w_large.png?1395542934" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {width:100%;margin:0}

.jumbotron {
  /*z-index: 1; the element needs to be positioned anything else other than static to be taken into account */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2)), url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk18j.png') repeat-y;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    animation: animateBackground 3s linear infinite; 
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container > img {
  display: block;
  animation: animatePlate 10s linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes animatePlate {
  from {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 1510px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://cdn.officialpsds.com/imageview/78/5z/785z6w_large.png?1395542934" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please give some context about your answer.. It will be really useful for everyone.